# What does the color coding in Greasemonkey's manage scripts dialog mean?

Tags: greasemonkey

In the screenshot below, the top script has a pure blue background, the second has some diagonal red bands in addition to the blue, and the bottom one is identical to second, except it is slightly greyed out.

I assume the greying out is because the userscript isn't enabled, but I can't figure out what the red bands mean. Does anyone know what the color codes mean, and are there any other colors I can come across in the manage scripts dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting Firefox chrome, I can see a CSS yellow highlight on those flagged for the attribute notification="warning". Digging through the Greasemonkey source, this is assigned when a script cannot be automatically updated. This would be because it doesn't contain any code or metadata to do so.

Note: I can see that you are using a fairly out of date copy of Greasemonkey as the styles in your screenshot are different from the Firefox addons window so the information here may not be 100% matched to what you have.